# Airtel dongle on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dongle

I got a new laptop from the Assam government with an Ubuntu 16.04 operating system. The Assam government has also given me an Airtel dongle with an Airtel sim and unlimited internet for 2 years, but connecting the dongle to my laptop I cannot find any response. I also searched in the settings, but I can't find any solutions.

Comment: After connecting the dongle open a terminal and type `ping google.com` and post the output. To open terminal hit these keys on your keyboard `ctrl + alt + t`

Comment: Most of the dongles sold in India have manufacturer supplied connection software only for Windows. You will have to try other methods than just looking in the settings

Comment: Try the second post mentioned in this thread https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2007622

Comment: @Yaksha That thread is very old. At that time installing the embedded driver was necessary but soon after the modem had native support. I suspect the OP here is in the same situation but expecting to see something *other than the mobile broadband settings appearing in the Network Manager indicator* is not the way to go.